# How to retain checkbox state after submit in django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Checkbox has two states(checked and unchecked).In my view I have several products and I am trying to filter it based on its category.When I click on any checkbox, checkbox state is changing(getting unchecked).Also I am unable to select multiple checkboxes.

Models.py,

```
class Add_cat(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField("Name")
    cat_name = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

My template file,

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myfunction(){
    document.getElementById("myform").submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="{% url 'welcome_user' %}" id="myform">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p >Categories</p>
    {% for i in My_Cat %}

        <input type="checkbox" name="cat_name" value="{{i.category}}" 
         onclick="return myfunction()" 
    {% if add_cat.cat_name %}checked="checked"{% endif %}>{{i.category}}    

    {% endfor %}
</form>
</body>
```

Views.py,

```
#Add_prod class contains product list with category as foreign key to Add_cat
def welcome_user(request): 
    categories = Add_cat.objects.all()       
    if 'cat_name'  in request.GET:
        filter_category = request.GET.getlist('cat_name')
        my_products = Add_prod.objects.filter(cat__category__in = filter_category)
        context = { 
                "My_Cat":categories,
                "products":my_products    
        }      

    if 'cat_name' not  in request.GET:
        my_products = Add_prod.objects.all()
        context = { 
                "My_Cat":categories,
                "products":my_products    
        }
    return render(request,"welcome-user.html",context)
```

Comment: What is `add_cat` supposed to be?

Comment: Its a database name

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is iterating with `i`, but your if uses an `add_cat`, change one of them to be the same as the other.

```
{% for i in My_Cat %} --> {% for add_cat in My_Cat %}
{% if add_cat.cat_name %}  -->  {% if i.cat_name %}
```

Comment: I've undeleted this for the time being, but I still think the `if` condition is wrong.

Comment: I changed if condition like this,   {% if i.category %}checked="checked"{% endif %} now all the categories are checked what to do?

Comment: @Bhanukiran - changing `cat_name` to `category` won't help since that will just check if the category has any text.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for i in My_Cat %}

    <input type="checkbox" name="{{i.category}}" value="{{i.category}}" 
         onclick="return myfunction()" 
    {% if add_cat.cat_name %}checked="checked"{% endif %}>{{i.category}}    
{% endfor %}
```

You are using the same name for all the checkbox, so when you change the state of one, you change the state of all you need to use `{{i.cat_name}}` instead of `cat_name`. This is the reason for all your checkboxes changing the name when you click in one.

Btw, I don't know your requirements, but for me, the name of your attributes are quite confuse. I would spend more time to rethink the name of the attributes to avoid more errors like this one in the future.